# Google earth plug in for Ubuntu

Tags: plugins, google-earth

I have a question. Is there any way to run google earth plug in in linux (Ubuntu, Lubuntu,...).

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Is it available for Ubuntu?

Comment: Officially not, but maybe there is unofficial version of it?

Answer (score 2):

Webupd8 had an article about installing Google Earth [last April](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-1404.html), and I assume that it still works.  There are some 32-but libraries that are required, and the commands below will install these:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxext6:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386

cd /tmp && wget http://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb

sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I was thinking about google earth plug in in firefox or chromium.

Comment: Ah.  The [Google Earth Plugin](https://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/plugin.html) website is pretty clear about that.

Comment: I have added the request for the Linux version of plug in on google groups.